# Being not admin user how to install local GCC instead of provided?

Tags: debian, software-installation, gcc, non-root-user

So I came into my classrom Debian is installed, and gcc 4.1. I want to install (compile from sources is an option - I have time..) for my self GCC 4.7 and adress it in bash as gcc anywhere. Is such thing possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `--prefix` option with the `configure` command.

I won't try to give a complete `configure` command here, since GCC is one of those programs most often given complex configuration options, but adding something like `--prefix=$HOME/my-gcc-4.7` will work. Upon installation, you will get a tree under that directory containing things like `bin/gcc`.

Once it's built and installed, add `$HOME/my-gcc-4.7/bin` to the head of your `PATH`, and suddenly it will become the default GCC.